# Complex trigonometric function

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that $\sin\left(2k\pi\right)=0$ ; for integer $k$
But I don't know  $\sin\left(2k\pi\,\mathrm{i}\right)\, =\, ?$.

Is it $= 0$ or not ? for any trigonometry function. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \sin (i\theta) = i\sinh \theta$

So $\displaystyle \sin (2k\pi i) = i\sinh (2k\pi) \neq 0$ for $k \neq 0$.

Here $\displaystyle \sinh \theta$ represents the hyperbolic sine function. $\displaystyle \sinh \theta = \frac{e^{\theta} - e^{-\theta}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact $\sin{z}$ has only real zeros. One may find the lovely formula
\begin{align}
\lvert\sin{(x+iy)}\rvert^2 &= \lvert \sin{x}\cosh{y}+i\cos{x}\sinh{y}\rvert^2 \\
&= \sin^2{x}\cosh^2{y} + \cos^2{x}\sinh^2{y} \\
&= \sin^2{x}(1+\sinh^2{y})+(1-\cos^2{y})\sinh^2{y} \\
&= \sin^2{x}+\sinh^2{y},
\end{align}
and $\sinh{y}$ is only zero when $y$ is zero. So the only roots of $\sin{z}$ are the real ones you know and love.